# How can i return the original phrase after determining if its a palindrome?

Tags: python, python-3.x, palindrome

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, link):
        self.data = data
        self.link = link

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class Deque:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def add_front(self, whatToInsert):
        temp = Node(whatToInsert, None)
        temp.link = self.head
        self.head = temp


    def remove_rear(self):
        c = self.head
        if self.head is None:
            return None
        if c.link is None:
            self.head = None
            return c.data
        while c.link.link != None:
            c = c.link
        valueToReturn = c.link.data
        c.link = None
        return valueToReturn

    def remove_front(self):
        self.head = self.head.link
        return

    def add_rear(self, whatToInsert):
        if (self.head == None):
            self.head = Node(whatToInsert, None)
            return
        else:

            temp = self.head
            while (temp.link != None):
                temp = temp.link

            temp.link = Node(whatToInsert, None)

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.head == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def size(self): # fix
        c = self.head
        sizeCount = 0
        while (c !=  None):
            c = c.link
            sizeCount += 1
        return sizeCount

    def __str__(self):
        c = self.head
        s = ""
        while (c.link != None):
            s += f"{c.data} -> "
            c = c.link
        s += str(c.data)
        return s

def isPalindrome(word):
  dq = Deque()
  for letter in word:
    dq.add_rear(letter)

    
  while (dq.size() > 1):
    if (dq.remove_front() != dq.remove_rear()):
      return False

  return True

with open("phrases.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
phrases = []
#normalize words
for word in lines:
    for char in word:
        if (not char.isalpha()):
            word = word.replace(char, "")
    word = word.lower()
        #add normalized words to list
    phrases.append(word)
        #make new list and add palindromes to the new list
pals = []
for word in word:
   if (isPalindrome(word) == True):
       pals.append(word)
       
print(pals) # ['w', 'a', 's', 'i', 't', 'e', 'l']
```

Right now the output is a list of letters that was the last letter in the middle of the palindrome because the front and rear characters in the phrase are removed until its just one letter left, meaning it's a palindrome. I can't figure out how to print the original phrase before it was normalized. I think storing a copy of the original phrases in a list then converting the list of normalized phrases and original phrases to a dictionary would work but i dont know how to implement that.

Comment: Store a copy of it before you modify it?

Comment: what is the Deque() method in your code?

Comment: added the Deque class

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to return the full word why haven't you tried doing the following:

```
fullword = ''.join(pals)
```

Comment: the list that is returned isnt the palindrome separated by letter. It is several palindromes with only one letter left in word due to taking off the rear and front letters to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looping through the characters inside of word, instead of looping through the words:

Use: `for word in phrases`
Not: `for word in word`

Also there is an easier way to check for palindromes. You can reverse the string like this:

```
the_string[::-1]
```

and compare it to the original string.

Comment: that doesn't work. also, I'm using a deque to check for the palindrome. All i need help with is returning the original phrase